# IntelliJ: breakpoints in Scala tests won't get hit

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm trying to debug a test in my `Scala` project.

`IntelliJ` runs the tests successfully, however the breakpoints in the tests never get hit.

**The breakpoints inside the *tested classes* do get hit during the test**, so I assume the problem is with `ScalaTest`.

[image: IDE Screenshot]

As you can see on the screenshot, the breakpoints are set in various places in the tests, however IntelliJ won't recognize them, and simply finishes the debugging.

Is there any way to make IntelliJ to hit breakpoints in scala tests?

**UPD1:**

I do not run tests with `sbt`, I run them with Scala IntelliJ plugin, like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Are you running your tests with `sbt`?

Comment: No, I'm running them with IntelliJ. I also run them with Maven but it doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. File - Invalidate Caches/Restart... (within IntelliJ)
2. Remove the system/caches/* (look https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs for location of caches)

Comment: Tried that, no effect

Comment: Hi @meltedspark, Could you please provide the idea.log. 
Within IntelliJ Help/Show Log in Explorer.

Comment: This answer may not work for your specific case, but this is a sound and logical step when having issues with debugging scala in intellij